# Tabledit for multiple tables create with loop

Tags: jquery, tabledit

Im creating X tables with dataTable and Tabledit with a loop, the main example i took it from https://www.webslesson.info/2020/05/make-editable-datatable-using-jquery-tabledit-plugin-with-php-ajax.html

the situation  is for each loop, the Tabledit is adding info from lastest columns + buttons (image)

[img with situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoffE.jpg)

and for each loop the number of data is less (size of loop)
what to do to fix that problem?

this is the code: (the other phps are the same of the link)
also, how to add row button to each table?

main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
html ="";
    for(x = 0; x < 5; x++) {

        html += '<table id="" class="tabla table table-bordered table-striped">';
        html += '<thead>';
        html += ' <tr>';
        html += '  <th>ID</th>';
        html += ' <th>First Name</th>';
        html += ' <th>Last Name</th>';
        html += '  <th>Gender</th>';
        html += ' </tr>';
        html += '</thead>';
        html += '<tbody></tbody>';
        html += '</table>';
    }

    $('#tab').append(html);

    //TRAE LOS DATOS DE LA BD
    var dataTable = $('.tabla').DataTable({
     "processing" : true,
     "serverSide" : true,
     "order" : [],
     "ajax" : {
      url:"fetch.php",
      type:"POST"
     }

    });

// i did this, but doest work:
      $addRowButton.on('click', function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        $dataTable.row.add([
            counter +'.1',
            counter +'.2',
            counter +'.3',
            counter +'.4',
            counter +'.5'
        ] ).draw( false );
 
        counter++;
      });

   // AGREGA Y EJECUTA BOTONES DE EDITAR, BORRAR
    $('.tabla').on('draw.dt', function(){
     $('.tabla').Tabledit({
      url:'action.php',
      dataType:'json',
      columns:{
       identifier : [0, 'id'],
       editable:[[1, 'first_name'], [2, 'last_name'], [3, 'gender', '{"1":"Male","2":"Female"}']]
      },
      restoreButton:false,
      onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
       if(data.action == 'delete')
       {
        $('#' + data.id).remove();
        $('.tabla').DataTable().ajax.reload();
       }
      }
     });
    });    
   });
```

index.php:

```html
<div id="tab" class="table-responsive">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the tables with [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and init each table separately.

Something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  html = "";
  for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    html += '<table id="" class="tabla table table-bordered table-striped">';
    html += '<thead>';
    html += ' <tr>';
    html += '  <th>ID</th>';
    html += ' <th>First Name</th>';
    html += ' <th>Last Name</th>';
    html += '  <th>Gender</th>';
    html += ' </tr>';
    html += '</thead>';
    html += '<tbody></tbody>';
    html += '</table>';
    html += '<button>Add row</button>';
  }

  $('#tab').append(html);

  //TRAE LOS DATOS DE LA BD
  $('.tabla').each(function() {
    var $table = $(this);
    var $addRowButton = $table.next();
    var dataTable = $table.DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "order": [],
      "ajax": {
        url: "fetch.php",
        type: "POST"
      }
    });

    $addRowButton.on('click', function() {
      $table.row.add([/*add_new_data_here*/]);
    });

    // AGREGA Y EJECUTA BOTONES DE EDITAR, BORRAR
    $table.on('draw.dt', function() {
      $table.Tabledit({
        url: 'action.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        columns: {
          identifier: [0, 'id'],
          editable: [
            [1, 'first_name'],
            [2, 'last_name'],
            [3, 'gender', '{"1":"Male","2":"Female"}']
          ]
        },
        restoreButton: false,
        onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          if (data.action == 'delete') {
            $('#' + data.id).remove();
            $('.tabla').DataTable().ajax.reload();
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mosh Feu, solved, im going to do some test but I think i solved!!!!

Comment: Do you how to add a add row button for each table? @moshfeu

Comment: Sure :) You mean this https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html?

Comment: Yes, that but im using classes not ID, so how do i do to identify what table im calling when i press de button? and add the row to that table

Comment: You can append the button next to the table, target as `$table.next()` then bind the `click` event just like in the example. I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for your help, maybe im missing something but doesnt work, in your update, what is t ( t.row.add ), I just copied exaclty and add exampled rows counter and doesnt work, im really confused :(

Comment: Sure :) I didn't know what exactly you want to add so `.......` is just a placeholder.

Comment: i want to add empty inputs, but even that, when i push the button nothing happend

Comment: Try to add `console.log('clicked')` before `t.row.add([/*add_new_data_here*/]);`. I'm not sure you can add **inputs** to the table, you can add **values**.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined, where do i have to defined t?

Comment: ‍♂️ I took `t` from the example but it should be a reference to the table - `$table` in this case.

Comment: i did it, and doesnt work, nothing happened, i update the code with what i did

Comment: I think you edited my answer. Try to edit the question

Comment: Have you tried to add `console.log('log')` in the `click` handler?

Comment: sorry, i just added code, same that you show me, but still there isnt any action

Comment: You didn't add the button's html - `html += '<button>Add row</button>';`

Comment: i didnt update in this code but in my console i did, im testing doing it with the link example and it doesnt work to

Comment: Can you create a working example (jsbin, jsfiddle, codpoen) so I could see the problem?